# JAX-WS - where are web service generated classes?

Tags: class, service, jax-ws, generated

I'm looking at pg 344 of the Java EE 6 Tutorial:

1. Uses the generated helloservice.endpoint.HelloService class, which represents the
   service at the URI of the deployed service’sWSDL file:
   import helloservice.endpoint.HelloService;

Where is this generated class? I included the WAR file of the service that's supposed to generate this. The service side is fine, as I can see the WSDL generated schema at
http://localhost:8080/helloservice/HelloService?WSDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in my java bin directory and didn't find wscompile, but I found a [wsimport][1] there. I think this is what is used in Java 6.

```
Overview 
The wsimport tool generates JAX-WS portable artifacts, such as: 

Service Endpoint Interface (SEI)
Service
Exception class mapped from wsdl:fault (if any)
Async Reponse Bean derived from response wsdl:message (if any)
JAXB generated value types (mapped java classes from schema types)
These artifacts can be packaged in a WAR file with the WSDL and schema documents along with the endpoint implementation to be deployed. also provides wsimport ant task, see Wsimport ant task. 


Launching wsimport 
Solaris/Linux 
/bin/wsimport.sh -help
Windows 
\bin\wsimport.bat -help
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link from oracle's [javaee tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC3.html):

The generate-wsdl Task 
    The generate-wsdl task runs wscompile, which creates the WSDL and mapping files. The WSDL file describes the web service and is used to generate the client stubs in Static Stub Client. The mapping file contains information that correlates the mapping between the Java interfaces and the WSDL definition. It is meant to be portable so that any J2EE-compliant deployment tool can use this information, along with the WSDL file and the Java interfaces, to generate stubs and ties for the deployed web services.

```
The files created in this example are MyHelloService.wsdl and mapping.xml. The generate-wsdl task runs wscompile with the following arguments: 

wscompile -define -mapping build/mapping.xml -d build -nd build 
-classpath build config-interface.xml 
The -classpath flag instructs wscompile to read the SEI in the build directory, and the -define flag instructs wscompile to create WSDL and mapping files. The -mapping flag specifies the mapping file name. The -d and -nd flags tell the tool to write class and WSDL files to the build subdirectory. 

The wscompile tool reads an interface configuration file that specifies information about the SEI. In this example, the configuration file is named config-interface.xml and contains the following: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-rpc/ri/config">
  <service 
      name="MyHelloService" 
      targetNamespace="urn:Foo" 
      typeNamespace="urn:Foo" 
      packageName="helloservice">
      <interface name="helloservice.HelloIF"/>
  </service>
</configuration> 
This configuration file tells wscompile to create a WSDL file named MyHello
Service.wsdl with the following information: 

•The service name is MyHelloService.
•The WSDL target and type namespace is urn:Foo. The choice for what to use for the namespaces is up to you. The role of the namespaces is similar to the use of Java package names--to distinguish names that might otherwise conflict. For example, a company can decide that all its Java code should be in the package com.wombat.*. Similarly, it can also decide to use the namespace http://wombat.com. 
•The SEI is helloservice.HelloIF.
The packageName attribute instructs wscompile to put the service classes into the helloservice package.
```